# How to replace multiple strings with possible overlap in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing certain tokens I want to replace.

For example

> @john and @johnathan went to see @sarah in their #hometown to look at
> her new #home.

I have a list of tokens:

```
handles = ["john", "johnathan", "sarah"]
topics = ["home", "hometown"]
```

I want to replace the handles with `<a href="/user/john">@john</a>` and topics with `<a href="/topic/hometown">#hometown</a>`.

I could simply iterate over the tokens and use simple replacement. But as you can see, I have overlapping tokens which complicates things. Additionally, I need to avoid replacing the links of already replaced tokens(which would also cause infinite loop).

I need to replace the tokens as not case sensitive(ie @john and @John are treated the same, the prefixed "@" is what makes the word inclusive for replacement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions seem like they would be your best bet for this.

I'm a bit of a novice still, but what you want can be achieved by running the **replace()** function in javascript on your string twice, each with a regular expression to match the users and hashtags respectively.

```js
var tmpString = `@john and @johnathan went to see @sarah in their #hometown to look at her new #home.`;
console.log(tmpString);

tmpString = tmpString.replace(/(@(\w+))/gmi, `<a href="/user/$2">$1</a>`);
console.log(tmpString);
tmpString = tmpString.replace(/(#(\w+))/gmi, `<a href="/topic/$2">$1</a>`);
console.log(tmpString);
```

This is pretty basic, but it will match a user based on the **@** symbol and break after any space (it accepts capital and lowercase letters, and numbers). The same applies to the hashtags, with the difference being the starting character.

---

Because I believe the above method could still be useful to others, I will leave it. Below I have an alternative solution that should fit your specific needs.

There are still a lot of unknowns with this so while this may appear to work for your example, it may not work for every scenario.

```js
var tmpString = `@john and @johnathan went to see @sarah in their #hometown to look at her new #home.`,
handles = ["john", "johnathan", "sarah"],
topics = ["home", "hometown"];
console.log(tmpString);

for(var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) tmpString = tmpString.replace(new RegExp(`(@${handles[i]})+(?![A-Za-z0-9])`, 'gmi'), `<a href="/user/${handles[i]}">@${handles[i]}</a>`);
console.log(tmpString);
for(var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) tmpString = tmpString.replace(new RegExp(`(#${topics[i]})+(?![A-Za-z0-9])`, 'gmi'), `<a href="/topics/${topics[i]}">#${topics[i]}</a>`);
console.log(tmpString);
```

This works based on the logic that any value in the **handles** or **topics** variable is meant to essentially be an exact match and can only be followed by non alpha-numeric characters. Meaning, if the handle is followed by a period, space, or exclamation point it matches. If it is followed by a letter or number, it is not a match. This fixes issues with things like *@john* and *@johnathan*.

---

As mentioned by another user, another method to use would be word boundaries. While the above method does in fact work for OPs original question here, I have included another possible solution that can be used as well.

```js
    var tmpString = `@john and @johnathan went to see @sarah in their #hometown to look at her new #home.`,
    handles = ["john", "johnathan", "sarah"],
    topics = ["home", "hometown"];
    console.log(tmpString);

    for(var i = 0; i < handles.length; i++) tmpString = tmpString.replace(new RegExp(`@\\b${handles[i]}\\b`, 'gmi'), `<a href="/user/${handles[i]}">@${handles[i]}</a>`);
    console.log(tmpString);
    for(var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) tmpString = tmpString.replace(new RegExp(`#\\b${topics[i]}\\b`, 'gmi'), `<a href="/topics/${topics[i]}">#${topics[i]}</a>`);
    console.log(tmpString);
```

Comment: Thanks. It could work but I have to use that list. Not all handles or topics that start with appropriate character are valid, so they cannot be made into links. Only those from the list. Which can have overlapping entries.

Comment: @glen I have updated the answer to work based on your criteria of needing to use the **handles** and **topics** variables to match values rather than pure RegEx.

Comment: thanks, but that does nothing(does not change anything in the tmpString)

Comment: My mistake. I did indeed forget to actually update the **tmpString** variable in the loop. Everything is good now.

Comment: Thanks. If use johna token instead of johnathan i will get this: `<a href=\"/user/john\">@john</a> and @johnathan went to see <a href=\"/user/sarah\">@john</a> in their <a href=\"/topics/hometown\">#home</a> to look at her new <a href=\"/topics/home\">#home</a>.` so sarah is broken.

Comment: I apologize. There was a typo in the loop (I was calling **handles[0]** for every person, which would always place john in the name, rather than **handles[i]** which uses the current name in the loop).

Comment: This will not work, because you do not use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: It will work and does. The code is available and can be tested right here. It does exactly what OP outlined in the original question and also attempted to cover some additional scenarios that were not asked. I have, however, included a third method that uses word boundaries as well. All 3 methods work and produce the same results.