# How to safely render tokenized HTML in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a text that contains certain tokens that need to be replaced into links. For example:

```
@peter and @samantha went on a date in #Paris to see the movie #HouseOfGucci
```

The result should be:

```
<a href="/user/peter">@peter</a> and <a href="/user/samantha">@samantha</a> went on a date in <a href="/topic/paris">#Paris</a> to see the movie <a href="/topic/houseofgucci">#HouseOfGucci</>
```

I have a list of tokens to be replaced(not all will be replaced) and how(users vs topics). This has been solved [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580642)

The problem now is that I am using Vue3 and I can render the html as simple `<div v-html="text"></div>` but this creates a problem because the links will cause full page reload of the Vue front-end, which is SPA.

The correct solution is to have a component that will tokenize the entire text and render each token appropriately via if condition(see below). Not only that, but also break lines need to be taken into account.

```
<template>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in lines" :key="index">
    <router-link :to="item.route" v-if="'route' in item">{{ item.value }}</router-link>
    <br v-else-if="'break' in item">
    <template v-else>{{ item.value }}</template>
  </template>
</template>
```

So I am trying to figure out how to process the input string and properly tokenize it and am a bit stuck on how to recursively cycle through all the tokens properly so they are properly replaced/appended/inserted into the final array to be rendered.

---

[Here is a Go code of the desired end-result](https://go.dev/play/p/NvEaTPB74lJ). I will try to implement it in JS, but if someone has better one, please do post it as answer. Also it does not handle the regex properly for prefix and suffix so `foo@samanthabar` will match `@samantha`.

Comment: I would try a bit simpler solution. Would use hashes for the anchors to prevent reloads, then use some navigation guard to listen hash route changes....; finally route to the related routes.  Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is what I came up with. I think it's quite ugly, but it works.

```
<template>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in lines" :key="index">
    <router-link :to="item.Route" v-if="item.Type === 'route'">{{ item.Value }}</router-link>
    <br v-else-if="item.Type === 'break'">
    <template v-else>{{ item.Value }}</template>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TokenizedText',
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    symbols: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    handles: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    topics: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
  },
  computed: {
    lines() {
      return new Token("str", this.text).Tokenize(this.symbols || [], this.handles || [], this.topics || []).Build()
    }
  },
})

function Token(type, value) {
  this.Type = type
  this.Value = value
  this.Route = {}
  this.Children = []
}

Token.prototype.Build = function() {
  let out = []
  if (this.Value.length > 0 ||this.Type === 'break') {
    out.push(this)
  }
  for (let i in this.Children) {
    out.push.apply(out, this.Children[i].Build())
  }
  return out
}

Token.prototype.Tokenize = function(symbols, handles, topics) {
  if (this.Type === "str") {
    let breakLines = this.Value.split("\n")
    if (breakLines.length > 1) {
      this.Value = ""
      for (let key in breakLines) {
        this.Children.push(new Token("str", breakLines[key]).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        if (key < breakLines.length - 1) {
          this.Children.push(new Token("break", ""))
        }
      }

      return this
    }
  }

  handles.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)

  for (let h in handles) {
    if (this.Value.toLowerCase() === "@"+handles[h].toLowerCase()) {
      this.Type = "route"
      this.Route = {name: "user.view", params: {handle: handles[h]}}
      return this
    }

    let handleLines = this.Value.split(new RegExp(`@\\b${handles[h]}\\b`, 'gmi'))
    let handleOriginals = this.Value.match(new RegExp(`@\\b${handles[h]}\\b`, 'gmi')) || []

    if (handleLines.length > 1) {
      this.Value = ""
      for (let l in handleLines) {
        if (handleLines[l].length > 0) {
          this.Children.push(new Token("str", handleLines[l]).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
        if (l < handleLines.length-1) {
          let line = handleOriginals[l] || "@"+handles[h]
          console.log(line)
          this.Children.push(new Token("route", line).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
      }

      return this
    }
  }

  topics.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)

  for (let h in topics) {
    if (this.Value.toLowerCase() === "#"+topics[h].toLowerCase()) {
      this.Type = "route"
      this.Route= {name: "topic.view", params: {tag: topics[h]}}

      return this
    }

    let topicLines = this.Value.split(new RegExp(`#\\b${topics[h]}\\b`, 'gmi'))
    let topicOriginals = this.Value.match(new RegExp(`#\\b${topics[h]}\\b`, 'gmi')) || []

    if (topicLines.length > 1) {
      this.Value = ""
      for (let l in topicLines) {
        if (topicLines[l].length > 0) {
          this.Children.push(new Token("str", topicLines[l]).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
        if (l < topicLines.length-1) {
          let line = topicOriginals[l] || "#"+topics[h]
          this.Children.push(new Token("route", line).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
      }

      return this
    }
  }

  symbols.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)

  for (let h in symbols) {
    if (this.Value.toLowerCase() === "$"+symbols[h].toLowerCase()) {
      this.Type = "route"
      this.Route= {name: "symbol.view", params: {symbol: symbols[h]}}
      return this
    }

    let symbolLines = this.Value.split(new RegExp(`\\$\\b${symbols[h]}\\b`, 'gmi'))
    let symbolOriginals = this.Value.match(new RegExp(`\\$\\b${symbols[h]}\\b`, 'gmi')) || []

    if (symbolLines.length > 1) {
      this.Value = ""
      for (let l in symbolLines) {
        if (symbolLines[l].length > 0) {
          this.Children.push(new Token("str", symbolLines[l]).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
        if (l < symbolLines.length-1) {
          let line = symbolOriginals[l] || "$"+symbols[h]
          this.Children.push(new Token("route", line).Tokenize(symbols, handles, topics))
        }
      }
      return this
    }
  }

  return this
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm guessing you want us to do your homework and not learn anything and that's not how it's supposed to be, so I'll try to help you without serving you everything pre-made and tested:

1. You could start by tokenizing the text as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26425713/7399497), splitting everything while treating the whitespace in between the words also as regular tokens. This will make it possible to get back the text's overall structure once you have handled your links.
2. Then you could loop over the tokens using a `<template v-for="token in tokens">`
3. Finally, you decide what to render using a `<template v-if="">` / `<template v-else-if="">`/ `<template v-else>` like this:

```
<template v-if="token.charAt(0) === '@' && persons.includes(token.substring(1, token.length))">
  <router-link :to="`/persons/${token.substring(1, token.length)}`">
    {{ token }}
  </router-link>
</template>
<template v-else-if="token.charAt(0) === '#' && topics.includes(token.substring(1, token.length))">
  <router-link :to="`/topics/${token.substring(1, token.length)}`">
    {{ token }}
  </router-link>
</template>
<template v-else>
  {{ token }}
</template>
```

You see? No recursion at all! Just simple linear code. You might run into performance problems with large sets of persons/topics, but once you get there, you should know that searching something in arrays is the culprit here.

Comment: Ok solution with one **big** problem. If searching the array can be a problem, why you making it much worse by including all this logic directly in the template? All this parsing and token lookup from `persons` and `topics` lookup tables should be extracted into a `computed` so it is not executed on each render but instead only if something in the input data changes

Comment: I have added a Go code of the solution I am after.

Comment: @MichalLevý for sure, it could be more efficient. One could implement the lookups as `Set`s in computed (using `has()` for lookup if the topic/person exists) and also do the transformation in a computed property so that, in the end, you only have O(n) for the whole text transformation and it is only triggered when anything changes. But from my point of view, that goes beyond what OP needs/needed. He asked how to get started solving his main problem.

Comment: @glen cool that you built a working solution! Some thoughts: I personally think that it's unnecessary to build a tree structure here, is there A reason for it? Also: You loop over every handle/topic/symbol for every line and try to match it, which is *best case* O(n*m), quite inefficient. A bit like what @MichalLevý commented on my answer. I'd therefor split the text first, which also prevents the `foo@samanthabar` problem. You might want to modify the splitting regex to allow ./,/;/: to act as word breaks, though. And then I'd look up the items from `Set`s, which makes every lookup O(1).